# ASP.Net Dropdownlist month and year values as parameters for SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, dropdown

I have two dropdowns, one for selecting the year and the other for selecting the month in my ASP.NET application.

I intend to use these two values for retrieving records from SQL Server database where the month and year of TxnDate column matches with the dropdownlist values, through a stored procedure.

Related Info:

- Stored proedure has two parameters `@Month` as `DateTime` and `@Year` as `DateTime`
- DROPDOWNLIST1 - Year (nchar(4))
- DROPDOWNLIST2 - Month (nchar(3)) Jan Feb etc.

TABLE1:

```
ID   TXNDATE    DETAILS
```

I read that the queries need to be SARGABLE instead of using functions, like, MONTH(TXNDATE). Help me write a stored procedure with the above info.

Comment: Which **version** (2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016) of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use next query as example:

```
select *
  from table_name
 where DATEPART(month, field_with_datetime) = @month --@month is param from your web-page
```